# Firefox 7 starts with an empty "Alert"-Window and browsing does not work

Tags: 11.04, firefox

Today, after I started Ubuntu (11.04) I noticed this window immediately after running firefox:

[image]

As you can see it is empty. No information about what is probably wrong. I closed the file and tryed to open a page (e.g. www.google.de). But firefox does not show any content. Browsing seems not possible.

I restarted firefox several times but the behavior did not change. Sometimes the this "Alert"-Window does show this text:

> Could not initialize the application's security component. The most
>   likely cause is problems with files in your application's profile
>   directory. Please check that this directory has no read/write
>   restrictions and your hard disk is not full or close to full. It is
>   recommended that you exit the application and fix the problem. If you
>   continue to use this session, you might see incorrect application
>   behaviour when accessing security features.

I have enough hard disk space (30 Gigabyte remaining free). I reinstalled firefox by the  Ubuntu Software Center, but the problem remained. I don't know how to proceed to track down the error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just googled the whole text from the "Alert-Window" as quoted above and google pointed me to a [support page from Mozilla](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Could%20not%20initialize%20the%20browser%20security%20component). There you will find 4 solutions to get rid of this problem.

In my case the file `cert8.db` in the Mozilla Profile folder was corrupted. I deleted it while firefox was closed and started firefox. Èt voilá firefox started without complaining.